# Average top n values where next cell equals value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

Having below data I would like to calculate average of top n values or top n% of values in column B where values in column A = C1.

I tried many different formulas but I can't get it to working.

```
{=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B14,A1:A14,C1,B1:B14,(IF(B1:B14>PERCENTILE(B1:B14,0.7),B1:B14)))}
{=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A14=C1,IF(B1:B14>PERCENTILE(B1:B14,0.7),B1:B14)))}
```

---

```
    A   B   C  
1   a   1   a  
2   a   1   cs  
3   cs  1   ffs  
4   a   1   .  
5   a   1   .  
6   ffs 1   .  
7   a   1   .  
8   a   1   .  
9   as  1   .  
10  a   1   .  
11  sfaq    1   .  
12  a   1   .  
13  aasf    1   .  
14  a   1   .  
15  a   1   .  
16  a   1   .  
17  qw  1   .  
.   .   .   .  
.   .   .   .  
.   .   .   .
```

[Image of worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1tbh.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think your `AVERAGE` version is on the right lines but when you calculate the `PERCENTILE` you also need the `column A` condition included within that calculation, e.g. this array formula

`=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A14=C1,IF(B1:B14>PERCENTILE(IF(A1:A14=C1,B1:B14),0.7),B1:B14)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You can get the same result with a regular (non array) formula using `AVERAGEIFS` if you use `AGGREGATE` function to calculate the `PERCENTILE`, i.e. like this

`=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B14,A1:A14,C1,B1:B14,">"&AGGREGATE(16,6,B1:B14/(A1:A14=C1),0.7))`

I expect the two formulas to give the same results